# Filter custom posts by IP address

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type named location.
Each location has custom fields like - city, state and zip. All separate fields as well as a complete address.

I'm trying to display a grid of no more than 3 locations that are closest to the users location by fetching their information by IP address. I am using http://ip-api.com.

I have a location that is within 10 minutes away however it keeps saying Nothing Available so it has to be the code.

```
<div class="locationArticles col-sm-12">
    <h2 class="relatedH2">Communities Near to You</h2>
    <div class="grid">
<?php

$remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

//$remote = '2600:1700:2f92:b000:306b:c4ed:bca1:ccc9';
//echo $meta;
$query = @unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'.$remote));
//echo '<pre>';
//print_r($query);
if($query && $query['status'] == 'success')
{                  
    $static_code = $query['region'];
      // GET POST ON THE BASIS OF POSTCODE
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'ilf_location',
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
            $state = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ilf_state', true);
            if($static_code == $state)
            {
                $allCode[] = get_the_ID();
            }
        endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
    endif; 

    $i = 0;     
    if(count($allCode) > 0) { 
        foreach($allCode as $pId) { 
            if($i <= 2) {
                $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($pId,'full'); 

                $mt = get_post_meta($pId, 'ilf_permalink', true);
?>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-grid">
            <div class="blogWrapper">
              <a class="blogIndexFeatured" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $featured_img_url; ?>');" href="<?php echo $mt; ?>"><span>View Community</span></a>
              <div class="card-body">
              <h2><a  href="<?php echo $mt; ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($pId); ?></a></h2>
<?php 
            echo"POSTCODE:" .get_field( "ilf_zip", $pId );
?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php 
            }
            $i++;
        }
    } else {
        echo '<div class="col-md-12">';
        echo '<h4>Nothing Available</h4>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
} /**if query status success**/
else {
}
?> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see `$static_code` being used in the SQL. Also, how are you calculating time between locations?

Comment: $static_code is the variable storing the query for the region from their IP. When removing the slashes before //print_r($query); will show you all the information it is pulling.

Not sure what you mean by calculating time between?

Comment: You say `within 10 minutes away`. It looks like `$static_code == $state` is the only  comparison though related to location. Should do more debugging and look at what those values are; and or if you even enter that `while`. Usually this is done with haversine formula. That gives closest location as crow flies though, if you want it by time/traffic/driving you'll need to be using some API for that.

Comment: Oh ok. What I meant was that I do in fact have a location that should show.
I am actually using a API - http://ip-api.com/php/.

I am wanting it to look at the region which is state from IP and compare to custom posts and show those that are near me.

Comment: But `dinosaur, colorado` to `burlington, colorado` is further than `dinosaur` to `salt lake city, utah`. How are you defining "close", `state` doesnt seem like a good rule. You also haven't identified where your current issue is with the code. We only know that `$allCode` is < 1 which probably means `$the_query->have_posts()` didn't bring back results orrr `$static_code`  never equals `$state`. We don't know what your values are so can't help much more than that

Comment: You should check the `$static_code` and `$state` variables. They appear to never be the same. Simply set a breakpoint and check the value of these variables. (Or output them with `var_dump`.) In case you do see that they are the same, check that the character encoding is the same. Or maybe html-tags where added.